# Update multiple rows with incremental counter greater than max

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update a column in multiple rows with an incremental counter starting at 1+max value in said column, so:

Original:

```
fkey   |  fval
--------------
one    |  1
two    |  2 
three  |  3
four   |  4
five   |  5
six    |  6
seven  |  7
```

Pseudo code:

```
update tabA set fval = (select max(fval) from tabA)+counter(1) 
    where fkey in ('two', 'six', 'four'); 
    -- counter starts at 1 and increments for each value
```

Desired:

```
fkey   |  fval
--------------
one    |  1
two    |  8 
three  |  3
four   |  10
five   |  5
six    |  9
seven  |  7
```

How can this be done (as efficiently) in Sqlite?

**Context**: I'm trying to run a queue on the table rows, and this operation would move a list of rows to the front (while also maintaining their relative order).

**EDIT**: Attempt 1:

Trying to use a counter view, but this fails as only the first increment is being used:

```
with recursive cnt(r) as (select 1 union all select r+1 from cnt) 
update taba set fval= (select r from cnt)+(select max(fval) from taba) 
where fkey in ('two', 'six', 'four');

sqlite> select * from taba;
one|1
two|8
three|3
four|8
five|5
six|8
seven|7
```

Comment: Do you require these specific values (8/9/10), or just any larger number?

Comment: Any larger numbers can do as the idea is to keep the sequence order.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the only requirement is that the new numbers are larger, you can just add a large enough value to the old value in all those rows:

```
UPDATE tabA
SET fval = fval + (SELECT MAX(fval) FROM tabA)
WHERE fkey IN ('two', 'six', 'four')
```

Comment: Thx. While this would give the batch as a whole top values, it would mingle individual rows. We want to maintain the order of the list of incremented rows as in the provided example (fval four > fval six ). I apologize for the inaccurate use of the word 'set'.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tabA set fval = temp2.newFval
from tabA as temp1 inner join (select fkey,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY fkey DESC)+ (select max(fval ) from tabA as temp3) AS newFval) as temp2 on temp1.fkey =temp2.fkey  
where temp.fkey IN ('two', 'six', 'four')
```

Comment: Have you checked this on Sqlite? It just gives a syntax error.

Comment: No, I have checked it in SQL server but you can customize it for sqlite